# UITextView's attributeText lost attribute value

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsmutableattributedstring

```
let myAttributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string)
myAttributedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: keyName), value: binding, range: NSMakeRange(0, tokenAttributedText.length))
```

the NSObject is base of binding

```
let spaceAttributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: " ")

attributedText.append(tokenAttributedText)
attributedText.append(spaceAttributedText)
```

then, delete the space with keyboard.Finally, I enumerateAttribute the key 'keyName', but the bingding is lost.

who can tell me what happen?

Comment: myAttributedText  = tokenAttributedText

Comment: I can't understand what are you trying can you explain it a little bit more?